# Is Lazy Sequence Assumed?

Tags: clojure

Can I safely assume that when

```
(gen-sym-map (gen-acct-num-sym @sym-count (gen-acct-nums 10)) 100.00)
```

is executed I have a lazy-sequence, or should gen-sym-map return the resulting map inside a lazy-seq function call?

```
(defn gen-acct-nums [range-end-idx]
    (vec (range 10000 (+ 10000  range-end-idx 1))))

(defn random-acct-num [acct-nums]
    (nth acct-nums (.nextInt random (count acct-nums))))

(defn gen-acct-num-sym [num-syms acct-nums]
    (loop [snum num-syms acct-num-lis []]
        (if (= snum 0)
                acct-num-lis
                (recur (dec snum) (conj acct-num-lis (random-acct-num acct-nums))))))

(defn gen-sym-map-day [acct-nums starting-bal]
    (reduce
        (fn [sym-map one-acct-num]
            (let [trans (random-trans )
                  amt   (random-amount )]
                (conj sym-map { one-acct-num (vector trans amt starting-bal) } )))
        {}
        acct-nums))

(defn gen-sym-map [acct-nums starting-bal]
    (loop [day-count-left @sym-day-count current-day 1 sym-map-local  {}]
        (if (= day-count-left 0)
            sym-map-local
            (recur (dec day-count-left) (inc current-day)
                    (conj sym-map-local {(gen-map-key current-day)
                                    (gen-sym-map-day acct-nums starting-bal)} )))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do *not* get a lazy sequence in this situation.

This is for various reasons:

- You are building a map. Maps aren't lazy, only sequences are.
- Most of your functions are written using loop / recur, which are inherently imperative and non-lazy.
- It's also worth noticing that [vec](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/vec), [reduce](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/reduce) and [count](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core) are also non-lazy, in the sense they need to consume the entire input sequence. So whenever you use these functions your entire sequence will be realised and you will lose the benefit of laziness.

If you want a lazy sequence in Clojure, the easiest way is usually to write your code in terms of higher-order functions that produce sequences such as [map](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/map) and [filter](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/filter). Most of the sequence-producing functions create lazy sequences by default.

You can of course wrap things in [lazy-seq](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/lazy-seq) if you want to construct a lazy sequence, but this requires the following:

- You output must be in the form of a sequence
- You have a way to construct your output lazily without realizing the complete result (otherwise using lazy-seq is pretty pointless....)

The classic use of lazy-seq would be to use some higher order functions and recursion to define a (possibly infinite) lazy sequence e.g. as follows:

```
(def fibs (concat [1 2] (lazy-seq (map + fibs (next fibs)))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What would you suggest is a good substitute for a map?

Comment: Depends what you are trying to do with it. But in general there's nothing wrong with (persistent hash) maps, they are a great data structure for many purposes - they just aren't lazy! If you really need laziness, then you will probably need to convert your code to create and use sequences instead.

Comment: Thanks for answering. What finally got me was the load time. I'm going back and re-working the problem.